# Excel: matching records from 2 sheets when people have multiple record dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have two Excel sheets: one with a list of people who have completed an activity, and one with a list of questionnaires administered to each of those people after the activity was done.

Sheet 1 (we'll call it **Activities**) has a person ID, the type of activity, the date the person completed the activity, and some other demographic info.

Sheet 2 (we'll call it **Questions**) has the same person ID, the type of questionnaire (which can vary depending on the type of activity), and the date the questionnaire was administered.

Since the **Activities** sheet covers a long period of time, there are many people who have done activities multiple times, so they appear numerous times in the list with different completion dates. Similarly, the questionnaires are (supposed to be) administered every time a person completes an activity, so the **Questions** sheet can also have multiple results for a given person, with different dates throughout the time period.

What I need to be able to do is pull info from the **Questions** sheet into the **Activities** sheet. I want to first have some sort of flag field to show whether a questionnaire was indeed administered after an activity (because this doesn't always happen), and then have a calculated field to show how much time elapsed between the activity and the questionnaire. The questionnaires often aren't administered until at least a couple of days after the activity, but the exact time frame can vary (hence why I want to be able to see it). Ergo, the questionnaire and activity dates rarely—if ever—match.

I can match records on the person ID, but since so many people have multiple records on each sheet, I need to be able to use the dates somehow as well. The **Questions** sheet *does* also include a field showing the activity date the questionnaire is for—is there a way to write a formula that matches records on *both* the person ID and that activity date?

Comment: So just to verify, activity date and the questionnaire date does not always correspond, but will be within a few days from each other. If the questionnaire was done though, there will always be an activity date in the questions sheet that match the date in the activity sheets. In other words, person ID & act date is a unique key between the two sheets. In that case, the solution is quite simple: create a new column in each sheet to create the unique ID with `=person ID & "@" & act_date`. You may now use that ID in a regular VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP function to pull in the questions sheet data.

Comment: @ExcelEverything ahh, good idea--I'll give that a try